# how to make the background color fill the entire element of a li tag

Tags: html, css

Hey so i have a horizontal nav bar, that i made using an li tag, and when i try and fill in the background of the "active" tag the background-color will only fill in just around the word and not the entire box `

```css
#menuBar ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

#menuBar ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 22%;
  font-size: 36pt;
  color: red;
  padding-top: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: thin;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

#content h1 {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.active {
  background-color: red;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuBar">
  <ul>
    <li class="home"><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="location"><a href="#">Location</a></li>
    <li class="history"><a href="#">History</a></li>
    <li class="culture"><a href="#">Culture</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Share your html please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `a` a block element and the issue will be fixed:

```css
body {
 margin:0;
}
#menuBar ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

#menuBar ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 23%;
  font-size: 36pt;
  color: red;
  padding-top: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: thin;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
#menuBar ul li a {
  display:block;
}

#content h1 {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.active {
  background-color: red;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuBar">
  <ul>
    <li class="home"><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="location"><a href="#">Location</a></li>
    <li class="history"><a href="#">History</a></li>
    <li class="culture"><a href="#">Culture</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

By the way i advise you to consider a better way to create your menu. Use flex instead of float:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#menuBar ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

#menuBar ul li {
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 36pt;
  color: red;
  padding-top: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: thin;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

#menuBar ul li a {
  display: block;
}

.active {
  background-color: red;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuBar">
  <ul>
    <li class="home"><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="location"><a href="#">Location</a></li>
    <li class="history"><a href="#">History</a></li>
    <li class="culture"><a href="#">Culture</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow that actually fixes every problem ive been ahving, pretty stupid with web design i appreciate the help thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Your solution works already

I tried it with this simple html

```
<div id="menuBar">
<ul >
<li>foo</li>
<li>bar</li>
<li class="active">active</li>
<li>baam</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kydyexsr/1/)

Comment: It would be better suited to inform the user about this, that the solution mentioned in the question already works, in the comments.

Comment: wow, without his html you were able to know that it's working fine ?

Comment: when i open it up the "background-color:" is only filling in quite literally just around the word itself, instead of the entirety surrounded by the border

Comment: @LukusKantor As other people have already suggested, to get a valid answer, please do mention your HTML in the question.